# Best method to replicate a website

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, replication

I have recently created a directory for a customer of mine.  The website is complete however he wants a replicated version of the website so he can test the website and learn how to use it.

To replicate his website fully it will take hours as I will have to change every hyperlink and URL in the website.

As my customer is being a little pushy and wants it done quickly I was wondering if it is posible to create a test website and add a little javascript that will replace his URL each time (until I create a full testing solution?).

For example if it was:

```
<a href="www.mydomain.com/contact-us">Test</a>
```

it would replace it to:

```
<a href="www.mydomain.com/test/contact-us"></a>
```

Is this posible?
Is it recommended for the time being, until I create a full test solution?

Comment: "_I will have to change every hyperlink and URL in the website_" - why? Did you not use relative URLs?

Comment: If all of your links, css, and javascript references were relative paths, it shouldn't make a difference where the website lives.

Comment: What does your development strategy look like? Do you have a development server that you tested code on? Maybe you could let your client play with that.

Comment: Talk about painting yourself into a corner... :P

Comment: On a side note: let this be a lesson for future webdevelopment. _Always_ make sure the (base) url is configurable so you won't have to change it every single time you copy the site to a different location. This could've taken you 5 minutes instead of 5 hours.

Comment: As a quickfix, open up the site files in Notepad++, then do a replace through files (N++ will do this automatically for you), replacing the live URL with a config variable, then set the URL variable as desired for the test site.

Comment: What's wrong with `Replace-All` which most editors have (which also can replace in several files)?

Comment: Unfortunately, the PHP software I use doesn't store URLs and paths relatively. what I will do is use the replace all function in Dreamweaver for all HTML files, and use replace all in my exported SQL file. Good thinking @MrCode. If you post that as an answer I will mark it as answered :)

Comment: @PeterStuart posted as an answer as requested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open up the site files in Notepad++ or any editor that supports file replacement, then do a replace through files (N++ will do this automatically for you), replacing the live URL with a config variable, then set the URL variable as desired for the test site.

Now you have a config variable for the URL, it will be easy if the client wants to change domain or you want to deploy elsewhere.

Answer (score 3):

You really should use relative paths so the files interact in relation to each other, regardless of where the files live.

That said, here is a possible quick JS solution you can use for the time being while you make your links relative instead of absolute:

```
$("a").each(function() {
  var href = this.href;
  href = href.replace("mydomain.com/", "mydomain.com/test/");
  this.href = href;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It is certainly possible to sort out your hyperlinks with javascript, specifically it would be really easy with a framework like jQuery.

```
$('a').each(Function(e){
 e.attr('href', e.attr('href').replace(/http:\/\/mainsite.com/gi, 'http://newsite.com'));
});
```

Hopefully the URLs in your css files, link hrefs and so on would be relative, otherwise you would need to change those too. At this point a php solution would be more appropriate.

Comment: `a` should be quoted like `$('a').each`

Answer (score 0):

The `wget` command-line utility has a `--convert-links` option. If you download a web site using that option, `wget` will convert the links in such a way that "local browsing works reliably."